# Cause of c# error when putting async for function

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't get an error when I set async for the Void function, but it gives an error for the function that has an output.
This code gives an error

```
public async static String H()
    {
        String url = $@"http://192.168.1.33:5000/Delete_Products?Name={h}";
        var h1 = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        return h1;
    }
```

Eror:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project  
File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1983  The return type of an 
async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, 
a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or 
IAsyncEnumerator<T> WinFormsApp20  C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\C\repos\WinFormsApp 
20\WinFormsApp20\Gropboxcs.cs   135  
Active
```

please help

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define your function like this:

```
public static async Task<String> H()
```

Every async function should return Task, try to avoid using async void if you don't have any reason to do so.

Comment: That's right, I will tick in 4 minutes